# Duvida em como desenvolver um Skill bar

Tags: java, jsp

Boa tarde, estou con dificuldade em encontrar qualquer coisa sobre skill bar, normalmente só encontro skill bar de porcentagem,e como a imagem de exemplo abaixo, queria desenvolver um campo onde o usuário possa adicionar sua skills, como no Linkedln.
Se alguém souber como desenvolver ou indicar algum conteúdo, eu agradeço.[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]